# Python Flask error while writing rows to CSV

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, csv, flask

My code gives a KeyType error to a server that I am trying to build with flask. It is Supposed to write three columns "email", "subject", "message" from a HTML5 Form.

The current request method is available by using the method attribute. To access form data (data transmitted in a POST request) you can use the form attribute.

Python server.py code:

```
def write_to_csv(data):
    with open('database.csv', newline='', mode='a') as database:
        email = data["email"]
        subject = data["subject"]
        message = data["message"]
        csv_writer = csv.writer(database, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        csv_writer.writerow([email,subject,message])


@app.route('/submit_form', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def submit_form():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.form.to_dict()
        write_to_csv(data)
        return redirect('/thankyou.html')
    else:
        return redirect('/error.html')
```

HTML5 code:

```
<form action="submit_form" method="POST" class="reveal-content">
   <div class="col-md-7">
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="true">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <select class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Select Subject" required="true">
              <option>Feedback</option>
              <option>Inquiry</option>
              <option>Website Improvement</option>
              <option>Recommendations</option>
              <option>Other</option>
           </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <textarea class="form-control" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Enter your message" required="true"></textarea>
      </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">Send</button>
     </div>
</form>
```

Error:

```
KeyError
KeyError: 'email'

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2031, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2017, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2014, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1529, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1527, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1513, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\Desktop\Tutorials\PROGRAMING\PYTHON 3\Websites\WebServerJFC\WebServerJFC\server.py", line 42, in submit_form
write_to_csv(data)
File "C:\Users\Jezon Fernando\Desktop\Tutorials\PROGRAMING\PYTHON 3\Websites\WebServerJFC\WebServerJFC\server.py", line 31, in write_to_csv
email = data["email"]
KeyError: 'email'
```

Comment: It looks like none of the input fields in your form have the `name` attribute. So for email, for example, you would set `name="email"` for the email input field. It looks as if no data is being sent to the server when you submit the form — you can verify that by inspecting Chrome Dev Tools — and that's why you're getting the `KeyError` — there is no key "email" in the request data.

Comment: Thaaaankuuuuu!!! U saved my life. u r the best. I will never forget u